# NSDatePicker autocompletes way too quickly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

I have a textual `NSDatePicker` with no stepper (only shows hours and minutes) and want the user to enter these by hand. Everything works as expected, but only if the user types very fast. It looks like after around 1 second the `NSDatePicker` runs some internal method `_userEditExpired:` and takes what has been entere`d so far and selects the subfield. Means if I want to put in 45 minutes and wait too long after the digit 4 it will just take 4 minutes.

Any ideas how to disable or at least lengthen that timeout?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Oops, sorry :)